# How to combine several statements into one that passed into method of JS?

Tags: javascript

I have several js statements like below

```
$('#' + xxx_slot_name1).children().remove();
$('#' + xxx_ad_slot_name2).children().remove();
$('#' + xxx_ad_slot_name3).children().remove();
$('#' + loreum_ipsum).children().remove();
```

I hope you get the idea. The statements all look similar; yet the value inside the #... is different. Also, there can be more than one or even just one such statement. I want these all put in a function that I can just call. Considering I am not sure how many statments there are, how to do this?  I do not want the method called seveal times for each statements. somehow I guess I can pass in parameters of all the values of #... and then it does the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

`$('#' + xxx_slot_name1 + ', #' + xxx_slot_name2 + ', #' + xxx_slot_name3 + ', #' + lorem_ipsum).children().remove()`

Just separate each selector with a comma to grap them all

Comment: Thanks. I knew it. Somehow the data was not coming out of the brain. Thanks a lot. It really helped it.